# How to know if HTTP request is GET or POST in Struts 2 action?

Tags: post, struts2, get, request, action

Is there a way to know in Struts2 action's method if this is GET or POST request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HTTPServletRequest.getMethod()` to find out that and handle accordingly in action.

Answer (score 5):

Your action should implent `org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware`, so your action class should have something like

```
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
// ...
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {    
  this.httpRequest = request;
 }
```

Then just do:

```
 String method = httpRequest.getMethod() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTPServletRequest.getMethod()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement `ServletRequestAware` just for this, you can get the method with 1 line:

```
String method = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getMethod();
```